Is there a way to automate the process of joining session hosts to a HostPool in Azure?
I am using the Azure SDK for Python to set up the following resources in Azure:

Resource Group
VNET
Network Interface
Virtual Machine
Hostpool

This works fine and the resources are created.
Now I want to join the virtual machine to the HostPool as a session host.
From what I can gather there is nothing in the SDK that does this and it is a manual process, using either the portal or a combination of cloud shell and running scripts on the actual VM.
Therefore would the automation approach be to?

Run cloud shell from the Python script to get the key for joining the VM
Inject a PowerShell script into the startup of the VM by installing the PS custom script extension

When I was investigating this, I couldn't find a way to run cloud shell commands from the python script.
